# OpenCV Circle Recognition in android devices

Tags: android, opencv

I am new to android app development. I need to develop a very simple app that could detect coloured circles.Can someone please tell me in detail how to use openCV Circle Recognition code in developing a simple android app that can detect coloured circles. I am currently using openCV+ Eclipcs but it does not allow me to compile the source code in to .apk file

I have already done what u are saying...I have done the following

1. I download the full NVidia tegra-devpack-2.0-windows-2013-02-06-14961502 and installed It contains both android ADT for eclipse and eclipse also. It also contains the open CV and it automatically configures everything.
2. Everything works fine when I make a new android app like “my first HELLO WORLD app” and I can even install it to my android phone that means everything is working fine and everything is configured correctly.
3. The problem arises when I try to import the source code of the “CVCamera” an common app for detecting circles in android devices
4. When I import it in the eclipse as an android project from existing code it gives me following 2 errors

   (a) Project 'CVCamera' is missing required Java project: 'OpenCV'

   (b) The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved.
5. I have tried lots of things I even tried to link the open CV library to the project but of no use
6. I have a simple objective I want to develop an android application for detection of coloured circles by using the already available code on the web. Please help me in achieving the following

I am using openCV4android . I can even create new apps but the problem arises when i try develop the application by using already made source code. I am using the sources code of the CV camera app which has been already developed by so many developers Following is the link of the error I am getting in the eclipse. 
  Please see [the image](http://postimg.org/image/7wiynj5mb)
 Following is the link of the CV camera application which I am trying to import 
**stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/OpenCV/CVCamera_Canny.zip** 
Here is the link for another error “Build path entry is missing: OpenCV” 
[image](http://postimg.org/image/6l9tt3v9j)

building workspace problim [image](http://postimg.org/image/lmxzuf92j/)

Answer (score 0):

Use opencv4android in eclipse.

Before that you should deploy android ADT for eclipse, or download bundle for android dev.

Then follow the tutorial at opencv official site to start your way to android.

Use hough transform for circle detection.

Comment: thanks brother for the welcoming answer, but i have already done what u are saying..i have done the following

Comment: Thanks brother for the welcoming answer, but i have already done what u are saying..i have done the following
1) I download the full NVidia tegra-devpack-2.0-windows-2013-02-06-14961502 and installed It contains both android ADT for eclipse and eclipse also. It also contains the open CV and it automatically configures everything.
2) Everything works fine when I make a new android app like “my first HELLO WORLD app” and I can even install it to my android phone that means everything is working fine and everything is configured correctly.

Comment: 3) The problem arises when I try to import the source code of the “CVCamera” an common app for detecting circles in android devices 
4) When I import it in the eclipse as an android project from existing code it gives me following 2 errors 
(a) Project 'CVCamera' is missing required Java project: 'OpenCV' 
(b) The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved.

Comment: 5) I have tried lots of things I even tried to link the open CV library to the project but of no use 
6) I have a simple objective I want to develop an android application for detection of coloured circles by using the already available code on the web. Please help me in achieving the following
7) Thanks in advances your answers are lifesaving and very motivating

Comment: i have updated all steps in my original question if u could please see the links of images and the link of sources file which i have given then u may get to know about the problem which i am facing..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You must link JavaCV lib into your project rather than OpenCV.

Android app cannot use OpenCV(C++) unless you use JNI, which is far beyond the scope of this question.

So please follow the tutorial for using JavaCV on Android rather than doing the import stuff on your own. Please make some JavaCV examples compile and run on your phone before you try to adapt the code.

Besides I strongly recommend you use [openCV4android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html), which is sure to work, rather than JavaCV + Android, which takes your considerable time coping with configuration and integration.

Comment: I am using openCV4android . I can even create new apps but the problem arises when i try develop the application by using already made source code. I am using the sources code of the CV camera app which has been already developed by so many developers
Following is the link of the error I am getting in the eclipse. Please see the image 
http://postimg.org/image/7wiynj5mb/
Following is the link of the CV camera application which I am trying to import 
http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/OpenCV/CVCamera_Canny.zip 

Thanks for your continued support. I am waiting for ur further guidance

Comment: Here is the link for another error “Build path entry is missing: OpenCV”
http://postimg.org/image/6l9tt3v9j/

Comment: @ SolessCHong.. i am waiting for ur advices.. have ur seen the links of CVcamera and links of the images which i have given in order to know the errors i am getting????